# if dentro de un foreach ¿se puede?

Tags: php, bucle-for, condiciones, programación-funcional

tengo una sencilla matriz donde se guarda lo siguiente :

```
<?php

$matriz = array(
    array(
        "[id] => id",
        "[message] => Gracias",
        " [created_time] => 2020-06-25"
    ), array(
        "[id] => id",
        "[message] => Gracias",
        " [created_time] => 2020-06-24"
    ),);

print_r($matriz);
```

pero al hacer un foreach para seleccionar una sola fecha o una fecha especifica, no me muestra nada :(

```
foreach ($matriz as $valor) {
     
    if($valor['2']=='2020-06-24'){
        
    print_r($valor['2']);
    
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega la matriz de datos y dinos por favor si obtienes algún error

Comment: Hola @Pedro y bienvenido,  si se puede hacer. ahora por favor puedes poner el error que te esta generando y date un recorrido  por el sitio para que veas como se pregunta.

Comment: no me da error, solo me aparece en blanco. como si no existiera,

Comment: Para ayudarte de manera mas efectiva necesitamos una muestra de tus datos para poder replicar tu escenario

Comment: se entiende ahora? disculpen soy un poco nuevo

Comment: yo ahi veo un array que contiene arrays.. por lo tanto valor es un array??? creo que tu problema empieza por ahi (y no digo que no haya mas problemas)...

Comment: si de hecho el foreach me lo ordena por decirlo asi.

Comment: ¿Tratabas de componer un array asociativo?

Comment: cuando intento colocarle una condicion, es como si no funcionara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que funcione tu caso, el if deberia ser:

```
    if($valor['2']==" [created_time] => 2020-06-25''){
```

Ya que tus valores de elemento 2 son esa cadena, empezando con corchetes, luego la clave, el indicador de asociación y luego la fecha...

En un bucle foreach, el elemento $valor va a tener en cada iteración cada uno de tus elementos que contiene $matriz.

El problema de concepto es de los arrays interiores , aparentemente quieres que sean asociativos. Sin embargo los estás agrupando dentro de una cadena. Tu matriz debería ser:

```
$matriz = array(
    array(
        "Id"=> "id",
        "message" => "Gracias",
        "created_time" => "2020-06-25T16:58:45+0000"
    ), array(
        "Id"=> "id",
        "message" => "Gracias",
        "created_time" => "2020-06-24T16:58:45+0000"
    ),);
```

Con esto ahora podrás acceder a cada propiedad de cada elemento en cada iteración. En tu caso te interesa comparar la fecha, por lo tanto tú código seria:

```
foreach ($matriz as $valor) {
    if($valor['created_time']=='2020-06-24T16:58:45+0000'){     
        print_r($valor['created_time']);
    }
}
```

Nota: esto último es un ejemplo, no tiene mucho sentido comparar algo con un valor y si es igual imprimir ese valor...

Comment: Gracias esto era.